# Exception al Insertar en la BD Oracle

Tags: java, angularjs, oracle, spring-boot

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

> 2017-06-23 10:35:07.365 ERROR 888 --- [nio-2019-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL [INSERT
>   INTO
>   TAB_EMPLEADO(N_COD_EMPLEADO_PK,C_NOMBRES,C_APELLIDO_PATERNO,C_APELLIDO_MATERNO,C_SEXO,C_COD_DOC,C_NUM_DOC,N_COD_AREA,N_COD_CARGO,N_ESTADO)
>   VALUES (?,'carlos', ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: índice de columna no vÃ¡lido] with root cause
>
> java.sql.SQLException: índice de columna no válido

Mi query es:

```
INSERT
INTO
TAB_EMPLEADO(N_COD_EMPLEADO_PK,C_NOMBRES,C_APELLIDO_PATERNO,C_APELLIDO_MATERNO,C_SEXO,C_COD_DOC,C_NUM_DOC,N_COD_AREA,N_COD_CARGO,N_ESTADO)
VALUES (?,'carlos', ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)];
```

Comment: agrega tu código, sólo la exepción no sirve prácticamente en nada.

Comment: No se si sigues interesado en la respuesta ya que no respondiste a la petición de que añadieras más código, pero por la excepción diría que tu prepared statement tiene más/menos valores de los que estas añadiéndole.

Comment: Con spring boot no necesitas definir las Querys. Si utilizas los repositorios con JPA puedes eliminar la línea y tal vez se resuelva el problema. Lo dejo por si alguien va buscando esta info.